# CentOS 7 Old Kernel Still Active

Tags: centos, kernel, yum

I'm trying to update the CentOS kernel. I've run `yum check-update`  and `sudo yum -y update` to pull in the latest packages and kernel. It now lists two kernels:

```
# yum list kernel
Installed Packages
kernel.x86_64                    3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7                installed
kernel.x86_64                    3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7               @updates
```

I've attempted to reboot. However, it still shows the old 3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7 kernel as active.

```
# uname -r
3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64
```

I've tried looking at grub but it still only lists the old 3.10.0-1062

```
# cat /etc/grub2.cfg | grep 3.10
    $linux ($root)//vmlinuz-3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64 ${extra_cmdline} net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0 quiet elevator=noop pti=off nomodeset nofb vga=normal console=tty1 console=ttyS0 console=hvc0 root=UUID=ddac8416-8037-4b93-a480-71c74b7ee6e7 rw
    $initrd ($root)//initramfs-3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64.img
    $linux ($root)//vmlinuz-3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64 ${extra_cmdline} net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0 quiet elevator=noop pti=off nomodeset nofb vga=normal console=tty1 console=ttyS0 console=hvc0 root=UUID=ddac8416-8037-4b93-a480-71c74b7ee6e7 rw  ide=nodma apm=off noresume edd=off nomodeset 3
    $initrd ($root)//initramfs-3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64.img
```

I've tried unsuccessfully removing "old" kernels

```
package-cleanup --oldkernels --count=1
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Not removing kernel 3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7 because it is the running kernel
No old kernels to remove
```

How do I install/use this new kernel?

Edit (More output):

```
# rpm -q kernel
kernel-3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7.x86_64

# yum install kernel
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: d2lzkl7pfhq30w.cloudfront.net
Package kernel-3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

# ls -l /etc/grub2.cfg
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 22 Mar  2 10:49 /etc/grub2.cfg -> ../boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Edit (**Fix**):
I started from scratch and noticed the following error when updating.

```
grubby fatal error: unable to find a suitable template
```

The following command and a reboot applied the new kernel

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Credit to https://serverfault.com/questions/673486/grubby-fatal-error-unable-to-find-a-suitable-template

Comment: You should verify that your `yum -y update` actually did update the kernel as YUM can be configured to not allow updating certain packages.  What is the output of `rpm -q kernel`?  What happens when you try to install it directly with `yum install kernel`?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /etc/grub.cfg`?

Comment: @GracefulRestart @jsbillings - I added the output of those commands to my post above. `rpm -q kernel` shows both kernels. `yum install kernel` says already installed latest version and nothing to do. There was no grub file so I listed the permissions of the grub2 file.

Comment: Excellent, just wanted to make sure the symlink is correct, and that you are booting via the legacy boot not UEFI.  I suspect that the kernel was installed but some part of the boot loader update failed.  A “yum reinstall kernel” should force it to re-run it.